# Flutter Firebase notification on IOS

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase notification with flutter. I want to get the data from the notification payload and redirect the user accordingly to that data.
I am using firebase `getInitialMessage()` in main.dart file.On IOS when the application is in the foreground or background, it works, but after the application is closed, `getInitialMessage()` always returns null. Works fine on android.
Can anyone help me solve this problem?